# Webfont gets cut off at certain window sizes

Tags: jquery, html, css, webfonts, typography

I am having a problem and I do not understand what is causing this. I have purchased a cool font to use in a responsive design. At certain window sizes, the font gets cut off by the edge of the window. Here is a screenshot:
[image]

Using CSS3 word-break somehow solves this, but I don't want to use it in this case. Are there any other options?
I would prefer a CSS only option, but if JavaScript or jQuery are involved I would be also ok with it.

The font used is [Armitage Black Italic from MyFonts](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/dunwich/armitage/black-italic/). Here is my CSS for that text:

```
.text {
    font-weight: normal;
    margin-bottom: 24px;
    color: blue;
    font-family: ArmitageBlack-Italic, sans-serif;
    font-size: 3.75em;
    line-height: .85;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: -0.29ex;
}
```

The problem can be recreated with any font as long it is large enough. If the font is in italics it is really obvious.
The text is inside this container:

```
.container {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 25px;
    background-color: grey;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: It’s really, really hard to help without knowing any of your CSS, or what your webfont is, or having a link to a demo page.

Comment: @minitech Sorry for that! I've added the font info and CSS. I would love to create a testpage, but as it's a font you have to buy it won't be possible I'm afraid.

Comment: Is it inside any container with a set width, or a `word-wrap` rule, or…? Also, can it be reproduced with any of your local fonts? Arial Black italic, or something?

Comment: @minitech I've just added the information to my initial question :-)

Comment: Does removing the `letter-spacing` fix anything?

Comment: @minitech No, the problem persists after removing it.

Comment: How about if `.container` isn’t `display: table`? (Come to think of it, why *is* `.container` `display: table`? That tends to break a lot of things.)

Comment: @minitech It is set to `display: table` so I can use `vertical-align: middle` on one of it's children. But removing `display: table` also does not fix anything. I just added some padding to `.container`, now it works but it still feels rather hacky.

Comment: So your problem’s sort of like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/6fs8j/)? (Adjust width of box as necessary to get parts of the last letter of “uniformly” hanging off the edge.)

Comment: Oh wow, yes this is my problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that your text is italic, the text will display outside of where it “is” — and with a large font, the problem’s worse. The only way to fix that is to hackishly add padding, as far as I know :(